# Sending a file from client to server gRPC in C# Example

Tags: c#, file, stream, grpc

Sending any type of file through gRPC with C#

Comment: Feel free to post any suggestions, confusion, or problem. I will be glad to help you.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is not the question...

Comment: Stackoverflow.com is q and a type of website... Posting  answer as the question doesn't make sens. You can always ask question and answer for it by yourself https://stackoverflow.blog/2012/05/22/encyclopedia-stack-exchange/

Comment: When a programmer search for an issue google mostly rank the stack overflow pages. The programming community also trusts this platform.
I think it's not an issue to provide something new, and good on this platform. 
This is helpful ultimately and I found it very useful. I spent time on this all so I think even it's quite helpful.

Comment: I hope you will remove the close request. I am not a blog writer to write a big blog on this.

Comment: But thanks for your feedback. Next time I will use encyclopedia-stack-exchange.

Comment: His point was that you should not *just* post this answer, but that you should write it up as a question, and then post the answer. Basically change it to a question like *How do I send a file from a client to a server in C# with gRPC?*, and then post the answer. (you can answer your own questions)

Answer (score 0):

***I didn't find a proper example of gRPC sending a file so I wrote the code and shared it with the community***.

**Client Code**

```
{
using var channel = GrpcChannel.ForAddress("http://localhost:5242");
var fileService = new IPaperService.IPaperServiceClient(channel);
byte[] file = File.ReadAllBytes("E:\\malicious_phish.csv");
PaperUploadRequest request = new PaperUploadRequest();
request.Paper = new PaperModel();
request.Paper.Day = "Day 1";
request.Paper.Session = "Session 1";
request.Paper.PaperBytes = Google.Protobuf.ByteString.CopyFrom(file);
request.Paper.FileExtention = "jpg";
request.Paper.StartTime = "08:30";
request.Paper.CombinationId = 1;
request.Paper.Decryptionkey ="Eex";
request.Paper.PaperTimeMinutes = 90;

request.Request = new GeneralRequest();
request.Request.Ip = "192.168.88.5";
request.Request.Mac = " asdf";
request.Request.HddSerial = "Asdfadf";
request.Request.Timestamp = "ASdf";

var call = fileService.UploadPaper();
await call.RequestStream.WriteAsync(request);
await call.RequestStream.CompleteAsync();
PaperUploadResponse response = await call;
Console.WriteLine(response.Response.Message);


Console.WriteLine("Press anykey to continue");
Console.ReadKey();
}
```

**Server Code**

```
public override async Task<PaperUploadResponse> UploadPaper(IAsyncStreamReader<PaperUploadRequest> requestStream, ServerCallContext context)
        {
            GeneralResponse response = new GeneralResponse();
            Console.WriteLine("Paper upload request received");
            if (await requestStream.MoveNext())
            {
                PaperUploadRequest request = new PaperUploadRequest();
                request = requestStream.Current;
                GeneralRequest generalRequest = request.Request;

                if(generalRequest != null)
                {
                    Paper paper = new Paper();
                    paper.Day =  request.Paper.Day;
                    paper.Session = request.Paper.Session;
                    paper.PaperStartTime = request.Paper.StartTime;
                    paper.PaperTimeMinutes = request.Paper.PaperTimeMinutes;
                    paper.DecryptionKey = request.Paper.Decryptionkey;
                    paper.FileExtention = request.Paper.FileExtention;
                    paper.PaperBytes = request.Paper.PaperBytes.ToByteArray();
                    try
                    {
                        myDbContext.Add(paper);
                        myDbContext.SaveChanges();
                    }
                    catch(Exception e)
                    {
                        response.Code = 500;
                        response.Status = "Failed";
                        response.Message= "Database Exception Occured";
                        response.Details = e.Message;
                        return new PaperUploadResponse { 
                            Response = response 
                        };
                    }
                }
            }

           
            response.Code = 200;
            response.Status = "Success";
            response.Message= "Paper uploaded successfully";
            Console.WriteLine("Done");
            return new PaperUploadResponse
            {
                Response = response
            };
        }
```

**Proto Files**

**Paper.proto**

```
syntax = "proto3";
import "Protos/general.proto";  

// The greeting service definition.
service IPaperService {
    rpc UploadPaper(stream PaperUploadRequest) returns (PaperUploadResponse);
    rpc FindAll(GeneralRequest) returns (stream PaperDownloadResponse);
    rpc Delete(DeleteRequest) returns (GeneralResponse);
}

message PaperDownloadRequest{
    GeneralRequest request = 1;
    string institute_id = 2;
}

message PaperDownloadResponse{
    repeated PaperModel paper = 1;
    GeneralResponse response = 2;
}

message PaperUploadRequest{
    PaperModel paper = 1;
    GeneralRequest request = 2;
}
message PaperUploadResponse{
    GeneralResponse response = 1;
}

message DeleteRequest{
    int32 id = 1;
    GeneralRequest request = 2;
}

message PaperModel{
    int32 id = 1;
    int32 PaperTimeMinutes = 2;
    string Decryptionkey = 3;
    string Day = 4;
    string Session = 5;
    int32 CombinationId = 6;
    string StartTime = 7;
    string FileExtention = 8;
    bytes PaperBytes = 9;
}
```

**General.proto**

```
syntax = "proto3";

message GeneralResponse{
    int32 code= 1;
    string status = 2;
    string message = 3;
    string details = 4;
}

message GeneralRequest{
    string ip = 1;
    string mac = 2;
    string hddSerial = 3;
    string timestamp = 4;
    string appId =  5;
}
```

Both General and Paper.proto files are in the same folder named Proto

I didn't find a proper example of gRPC sending a file so I wrote the code and shared with the community.